Policy Violation GraphAPI
I used the following code to apply a policy violation, and it is working fine:
public static void PolicyViolation(string chatId, string messageId)
{
    try
    {
        GraphServiceClient graphClient = StaticVariables.GetGraphServiceClientAsync();

        ChatMessage updatedMessage = new ChatMessage();
        updatedMessage.PolicyViolation = new ChatMessagePolicyViolation()
        {
            PolicyTip = new ChatMessagePolicyViolationPolicyTip()
            {
                GeneralText = "Custom Text to block message",
                MatchedConditionDescriptions = new List<string>() { "Global (Org-wide default)" }
            },
            DlpAction = ChatMessagePolicyViolationDlpActionTypes.BlockAccess,
            VerdictDetails = ChatMessagePolicyViolationVerdictDetailsTypes.AllowFalsePositiveOverride,
        };

        var result1 = graphClient.Chats[chatId].Messages[messageId].PatchAsync(updatedMessage).Result;
        Console.WriteLine("Policy Violation Applied.");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}

This code gives me the option to "Report this message and send" within Microsoft Teams. However, when I do this, I don’t receive any alert or email as an admin.
Where do we receive notifications when a user reports these policy-violated messages to the admin?


We are checking this with engineering team, we will update you soon.

Policy violations are typically set by a data loss prevention (DLP) application. DLP applications monitor chats for messages that contain data that users aren't supposed to send.
Ref Doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/chatmessagepolicyviolation?view=graph-rest-1.0

Hi @Nivedipa-MSFT,
Thank you for sharing the link.
I’ve created a custom DLP application, and it’s through this application that I’m enabling the policy violation flag. However, I still have a question: Where can an admin view the messages that end users report via the Microsoft Teams pop-up? I don’t believe this falls under the responsibility of the DLP application.

When end users report messages through the Microsoft Teams pop-up, admins can access these reported messages in the Microsoft Defender portal. Specifically, the reported messages will be displayed on the "User reported" tab on the "Submissions" page in the Microsoft Defender portal.
Please refer below document for checking configuration settings for user reported messages:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/defender-office-365/submissions-teams
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/defender-office-365/submissions-user-reported-messages-custom-mailbox


I’ve followed this documentation, and when we manually report regular messages using "More actions" > "Report this message," I receive email alerts and see them in the Defender portal.
However, when applying the policy violation flag via Graph API, then report message via Teams, the reported messages don’t appear in the portal. M/S Support closed my ticket, citing it as a developer issue, and advised raising it on Stack Overflow or M/A Q&A.
If possible, could you try applying the policy violation via the Graph API and reporting it from Teams? I suspect you will also face the same issue,
